# stacking axes horizontally on top of each other

Tags: d3.js

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2066415)is an example by Mike Bostock of a "simple" hive graph (as he refers to it [in this article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/hive/) ). It has three "axis" created by this code

```
svg.selectAll(".axis")
    .data(d3.range(3))
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d)) + ")"; })
    .attr("x1", radius.range()[0]) 
    .attr("x2", radius.range()[1]);
```

As you can see from the first link, the three "axes" form a circle, which seems to be accomplished by the rotation in the "transform" of the code above and use of these `angle` and `degrees` functions

```
var angle = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(4)).rangePoints([0, 2 * Math.PI]),

function degrees(radians) {
  return radians / Math.PI * 180 - 90;
}
```

Question: if there were only two "axes", how would it be possible (using a "translate") to stack the "axes" on top of each other (i.e. as two horizontal lines parallel to each other?

In my attempt to do this, I tried to remove the rotation of the "axis" and then to space them vertically. To stop the rotation,I removed the call to "degrees" like this

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
```

and I also set the range of the angles to be 0,0

```
d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["one", "two"]).range([0,0]);
```

then , to space the axes, I included a "translate" like this

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + width /2 + "," + height/d + ")"});
```

The result is that there is one visible horizontal axis, and it seems the other one exists but is only detectable when I run the mouse over it ( and the nodes and lines haven't been repositioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after but two "axis" stacked vertically can be achieved with:

```
var angle = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(3)) //<-- only calculate angles for 2 [-90, 90]
  .rangePoints([0, 2 * Math.PI]),
...
svg.selectAll(".axis")
  .data(d3.range(2)) //<-- 2 lines
```

**EDITS**

What are you are describing is not really a hive plot and attempting to re-purpose the layout is probably more trouble then it's worth.  If you just want linked points on a line, here's an off-the-cuff implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.axis, .node {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.hive.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 500;

var lineSep = 200,
    lineLen = 400,
    color = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(20)),
    margin = [50,50];

var nodes = [
  {x: 0, y: .1},
  {x: 0, y: .9},
  {x: 0, y: .2},
  {x: 1, y: .3},
  {x: 1, y: .1},
  {x: 1, y: .8},
  {x: 1, y: .4},
  {x: 1, y: .6},
  {x: 1, y: .2},
  {x: 1, y: .7},
  {x: 1, y: .8}
];

var links = [
  {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[3]},
  {source: nodes[1], target: nodes[3]},
  {source: nodes[2], target: nodes[4]},
  {source: nodes[2], target: nodes[9]},
  {source: nodes[3], target: nodes[0]},
  {source: nodes[4], target: nodes[0]},
  {source: nodes[5], target: nodes[1]}
];

var nodeNest = d3.nest().key(function(d){ return d.x }).entries(nodes);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin[0] + "," + margin[1] + ")");

var axis = svg.selectAll(".axis")
    .data(nodeNest);
    
var g = axis
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) { 
    var t = "translate(0," + (i * lineSep) + ")";
    return t;
  })
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("x2", lineLen);

axis.selectAll(".node")
  .data(function(d){
    d.values.forEach(function(q){
      q.len = d.values.length;
    })
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i, j) { 
    d.cx = ((i + 0.5) * (lineLen / d.len));
    d.cy =  (j * lineSep);
    return d.cx;
  })
 .attr("r", 5)
 .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.x); });
 
svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d){
    console.log(d);
    var p = "";
    p += "M" + d.source.cx + "," + d.source.cy;
    p += "Q" + "0," + ((margin[1] / 2) + (lineSep/2));
    p += " " + d.target.cx + "," + d.target.cy;
    return p;
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { 
    return color(d.source.x); 
  });

function degrees(radians) {
  return radians / Math.PI * 180 - 90;
}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, but what I'm actually after is to stack them horizontally (i.e. two horizontal lines stacked ontop of each other, with spacing between). I played with your code and couldn't figure out (partly because I'm not sure if `.rangePoints([0, 2*Math.PI])` is meant to determine the angle of the axes or the nodes. Anyways can you show me how to stack them horizontally thank you so much